# How to read the source code of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently, I want to learn from the famous project, jQuery. But there are so many source files, and I'm confused where to start?

About me, I have used jQuery for years, and before I post this problem I have read their Github page and and some external links on it, but I need more details. Such as which file should I read first?

Can somebody give me a clue where should I start?

What is the best routine you found to learn jQuery?

What rules should I follow?

Any small tip is welcomed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking at just wanting to read something, a good place to start with some understanding about jQuery might be from [here](http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/). This looks really nice.

It is annotated source code and even though the version is `1.6.2` it might be a good place to start.

From the website:

> Please Note:
>   This project was released in 2011 when 1.6.2 was the latest jQuery version. It is no longer maintained

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)

**jQuery - New Wave JavaScript**

Contribution Guides

In the spirit of open source software development, jQuery always encourages community code contribution. To help you get started and before you jump into writing code, be sure to read these important contribution guidelines thoroughly:

1.[Getting Involved](http://contribute.jquery.org/)

2.[Core Style Guide](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/)

3.[Writing Code for jQuery Foundation Projects](http://contribute.jquery.org/code/)

**Environments in which to use jQuery**

> Browser support differs between the master (2.x) branch and the
>   1.x-master branch. Specifically, 2.x does not support legacy browsers such as IE6-8. The jQuery team continues to provide support for legacy
>   browsers on the 1.x-master branch. Use the latest 1.x release if
>   support for those browsers is required. See browser support for more
>   info.
>       To use jQuery in Node, browser extensions, and other non-browser environments, use only 2.x releases. 1.x does not support these
>   environments.

**What you need to build your own jQuery**

> In order to build jQuery, you need to have Node.js/npm latest and git
>   1.7 or later. (Earlier versions might work OK, but are not tested.)

For Windows you have to download and install git and Node.js.

Mac OS users should install Homebrew. Once Homebrew is installed, run brew install git to install git, and brew install node to install Node.js.

Linux/BSD users should use their appropriate package managers to install git and Node.js, or build from source if you swing that way. Easy-peasy.